# how to catch status in a variable?

Tags: php, variables, switch-statement

i have following problem:

i look for a variable to work with that comes from a fetch_object. the table has a standard value that will be changed by a if clause. in the further code i need to handle two status properties so that i need to know how can i get one or more variables from a switch clause?

i need something like:

```
$row = $query->fetch_object();
    $Status = $row->Status;
        $1 = switch($Status){case "1"};
        $2 = switch($Status){case "2"};
```

or is there another way to realize that? it seems like switch is the onliest way to catch the status, isn't it? thanks alot.

Comment: you can cast it to (int)$Status

Comment: You don't "need something like this", because this doesn't really make any sense. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: i have a table where i get the different status types from. i use them to look for a a specific status the user have. if the user have for example status s1, then he is not allowed to make entries or another example, he can´t see something. these data i won't store into a session.

Comment: What's wrong with `if ($status == 1) ...`?

Comment: because i have another clause: if($query->num_rows===1 AND $Status=='S1'){... wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row = $query->fetch_object();
$Status = $row->Status;

switch($Status){
    case "1" : 
        // do something for case "1"
        break;
    case "2" :
        // do something for case "2"
        break;
    default : 
        // 
}
```

could this help you?

modified code:

```
$row = $query->fetch_object();
$Status = $row->Status;

if($query->num_rows){
    if($Status == "S1"){
        // status 1
    }
    else {
        // status 2
    }
}
```

Comment: no, because i need to to have something like <?php if(isset($S1)):?> to hide or show something.

Comment: I get it. If so, then you can simply say `$Status = $row->Status; $S = "S$Status"; $$S = "yes";` which will result in $S1 = "yes" if Status = 1 or $S2 = "yes" if Status = 2. But I think this is not the efficient way to do it!

Comment: what would be a better way to do so? thx

Comment: i found a mistake i wrote. in the table it is S1, S2, not only a integer. sorry.

Comment: what are those two status codes? Are they ("1" and "2") or ("S1" and "S2") ?

Comment: so would it be possible to do it like: $S1 = $Status = "S1"// $S2 = $Status = "S2"?

Comment: they are enums with 'S1', 'S2'!

Comment: you don't have to! I have edited my answer. Please check that again. It should help you :)

Comment: tried to do so. first part works fine. thanks. but i get in trouble with the html code. i get: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting ',' or ')'  when using <?php if(isset($Status == "S1")):?>
    <div></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: you should not write **isset**. the isset function accepts only variables, not expressions, it checks if a variable is set (is defined). In your context, you'd rather use it as `<?php if(isset($Status) && $Status == "S1"):?>` Got it?

Comment: thats why i was asking for this question :) thanks alot && best wishes.